# Harmonic Function Analog

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, laplacian

A function is harmonic if its non-mixed second partial derivatives with respect to each input sum to $0$.  Is there a similar notion for the sum of a function's first partial derivatives, or for any other derivatives?  If not, why is this attribute only useful in conjunction with the second partial derivative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define such a notion, but it probably wouldn't be particularly useful.  One thing that's special about the sum of the second derivatives is that it is invariant under orthogonal transformations.